# Convert date to day of week into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I would like to convert a SQL query in MS Access into SQL Server. This query is about converting date into day of week. Please advise.

MS Access:

```
UPDATE Contact_Hist 
SET WK_DAY = weekdayname(weekday(cdate(mid(date_id,5,2) & "/" & right(date_id,2) & "/" & left(date_id,4))));
```

For instance, `DATE_ID = 20140703` as per the table (`Contact_Hist`) and would like to convert to the day of week i.e. `'Thursday'`.

Comment: DATENAME(DW, GETDATE()) will return 'Thursday', in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS SQL Server 2012, you can do the following and get "Friday" back:

```
SELECT DATENAME ( weekday , '20140704' )
```

as demonstrated by this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc24a/8

---

So do:

```
UPDATE Contact_Hist SET WK_DAY = DATENAME ( weekday , date_id )
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! But I am still getting error while running the query. The date_id is a float data type and has to be converted into date. Can you please help?

Comment: Are you casting it to a date or string?

Comment: @user3802118 you can convert to int and then varchar/string this way: `SELECT DATENAME ( weekday , CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(int,20140704.0))) )` so your full query would end up being `UPDATE Contact_Hist SET WK_DAY = DATENAME ( weekday , (CONVERT(varchar,CONVERT(int,20140704.0))) )`

Answer (score 2):

You should use SQL Server's `DatePart()` function:

```
DatePart(weekday, Cast('20140703' AS date))
```

This will return an integer between 1 <strike>(Monday)</strike> and 7 <strike>(Sunday)</strike> inclusive.

<sub>*<edit2>*</sub>

How the `DatePart()` return value [integer] is interpreted is determined by SQL Server's `SET DATEFIRST` setting (or default configuration). That is, whether a returned 1 is Monday, 2 is Monday, and so on.

<sub>*</edit2>*</sub>

<sub>*<edit>*</sub>

To get the name of the day of the week use the `DateName()` function.

```
DateName(weekday, Cast('20140703' AS date))
```

For reference purposes, both `DatePart()` and `DateName()` take a "date" (that is, a *time*, *date*, *smalldatetime*, *datetime*, *datetime2*, or *datetimeoffset* value) as the 2nd parameter. SQL Server will implicitly convert a date string into a date, so the `CAST('20140703' AS date)` is *not* required.

<sub>*</edit>*</sub>

Comment: You can use `DATENAME` to get a string instead of an integer.

Comment: `1 (Monday) ` - I'm seeing Monday as 2.

Comment: This value is dependent upon how your server's `SET DATEFIRST` is configured.